# DAC Field UI warning indicator behaving like error

Tags: acumatica

I am raising a warning message on a field in its FieldUpdating event handler, but it is displaying and behaving like an error instead of a warning.  In other words, red instead of yellow icon, and turns the field value red.  Any ideas why it might be behaving like this?  Below is the exception being thrown.  I have also tried sender.RaiseExceptionHandling, and putting this in the FieldVerifying instead, but it still shows as error.

```
throw new PXSetPropertyException(string.Format("Instead of using this description, consider using the existing description: '{0}'",
                            closestFound.Key.Description, PXErrorLevel.Warning));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to behave like I want by using PXUIFieldAttribute.SetWarning instead of raising an error.  Maybe PXErrorLevel.Warning doesn't actually behave like a warning, not sure.

Comment: PXUIFieldAttribute.SetWarning is the preferred method in most contexts. Throwing exceptions will be more likely to break persist operations.